# Laravel, Behat & Faker Issue with Hidden Attributes

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm using Laravel with the following libraries:

- [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/)
- [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)

On the User model I have the password attribute hidden, so when I do a GET It's working as expected, show all the attributes least password

Now when I do a POST with with a model created form Faker I can't send the attribute Password.

**Faker Factory**

```
<?php

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $role = App\Role::all()->random(1);
    return [ 
        'role_id' => $role->id,
        'username' => $faker->userName,
        'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

protected $hidden = [ 'password' ];

/* rest of the code */
/* I have a validation rule for password to be required */
```

**User Context Function**

```
<?php
/**
 * @When I try to save a valid user   
*/
public function iTryToSaveAValidUser()
{
    $modelFake = factory('App\User')->make();
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $data['data'] = $modelFake;
    $res = $client->request('POST', url($this->apiURL . '/user'),[ 'json' => $data ]);
}
```

The error I'm getting is the password required, there is a way to set hidden ONLY on GET?

I "Fixed" this issue with the following code but I don't like this way

```
<?php
/**
 * @When I try to save a valid user   
*/
public function iTryToSaveAValidUser()
{
    $modelFake = factory('App\User')->make();
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $modelArray = $modelFake->toArray();
    $modelArray['password'] = str_random(10);
    $data['data'] = $modelArray;
    $res = $client->request('POST', url($this->apiURL . '/user'),[ 'json' => $data ]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this is due to this line

```
$res = $client->request('POST', url($this->apiURL . '/user'),[ 'json' => $data ]);
```

where you send attribute as json.

Read this properly,It can help.

**[Hiding Attributes From JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)**

Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes, such as passwords, that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do so, add a $hidden property definition to your model:

> Note: When hiding relationships, use the relationship's method name,
>   not its dynamic property name.

Alternatively, you may use the visible property to define a white-list of attributes that should be included in your model's array and JSON representation:

```
protected $visible = ['password']
```

**Temporarily Modifying Property Visibility**

If you would like to make some typically hidden attributes visible on a given model instance, you may use the makeVisible method. The makeVisible method returns the model instance for convenient method chaining:

```
return $user->makeVisible('attribute')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks!! I added `$modelFake->makeVisible('password');` into the Context Function and works perfectly!